# IS there anyway to change the width of the caret in unity code?

Tags: unity-game-engine, caret

I needed to change the size of my background, and this required changing the width of my input field. Somehow the caret width is extremely high, even though in the inspector it says it is on 1?

You can see my input box there and the size of the caret

[image]

I'm not sure if this is just a bug or something?

[image: This is my inspector]

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Did you maybe scale the input field via the `Scale` in the Inspector of the `RectTransform` or any of its parents?

Comment: @derHugo Thanks I sorted it out, I made the whole input system a child of my console, which didn't have a good scale so detached it :), thank you

Comment: That's what I thought ;) Glad you figured it out